# Checking for duplicates in a collection

Tags: c#, .net, .net-2.0

Suppose you have a collection of `Foo` classes:

```
class Foo
{
    public string Bar;
    public string Baz;
}

List<Foo> foolist;
```

And you want to check this collection to see if another entry has a matching `Bar`.

```
bool isDuplicate = false;
foreach (Foo f in foolist)
{
     if (f.Bar == SomeBar)
     {
         isDuplicate = true;
         break;
     }
}
```

`Contains()` doesn't work because it compares the classes as whole.

Does anyone have a better way to do this that works for .NET 2.0?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
fooList.Exists(item => item.Bar == SomeBar)
```

That's not LINQ, but a Lambda expression, but nevertheless, it uses a v3.5 feature.  No problem:

```
fooList.Exists(delegate(Foo Item) { return item.Bar == SomeBar});
```

That should work in 2.0.

Answer (score 4):

Implement the [IEqualityComparer<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx) interface, and use the matching [Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339118.aspx) method.

```
public class MyFooComparer: IEqualityComparer<Foo> {

   public bool Equals(Foo foo1, Foo foo2) {
      return Equals(foo1.Bar, foo2.Bar);
   }

   public int GetHashCode(Foo foo) {
      return foo.Bar.GetHashCode();
   }
}

Foo exampleFoo = new Foo();
exampleFoo.Bar = "someBar";
if(myList.Contains(exampleFoo, new MyFooComparer())) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: um... you define the IEqualityComparer, but you don't actually use it.

Answer (score 0):

fooList.Exists(item => item.Bar == SomeBar)

or with anonymous delegate

fooList.Exists(delegate(Foo item) {return item.Bar == SomeBar;})

Answer (score 0):

If you need the element, you can also use List.Find() and pass in a delegate that returns true for your definition of a "match" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc.aspx).

There's an example of how to define a delegate on that MSDN doc.

Answer (score 0):

If the 'Bar's for your class are unique (a key to class Foo), then you can try implementing a System.Collections.ObjectModel.KeyedCollection.  It's pretty simple:  just implement the GetKeyForItem() method.

```
class Foo
{
    public string Bar;
    public string Baz;
}

class FooList : KeyedCollection<string, Foo>
{
    protected override string GetKeyForItem(Foo item)
    {
        return item.Bar;
    }
}

FooList fooList;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you override Equals on Foo to make key on Bar, Contains() will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use LINQ you can do the following:

```
bool contains = foolist.Where(f => f.Bar == someBar).Count() != 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are 4 ways to check if the collection has no duplicates:

```
public static bool LinqAll<T>(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
{
    HashSet<T> set = new();

    return !enumerable.All(set.Add);
}

public static bool LinqAny<T>(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
{
    HashSet<T> set = new();

    return enumerable.Any(element => !set.Add(element));
}

public static bool LinqDistinct<T>(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
{
    return enumerable.Distinct().Count() != enumerable.Count();
}

public static bool ToHashSet<T>(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
{
    return enumerable.ToHashSet().Count != enumerable.Count();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You probably want to use C5.HashSet, and implement Equals and GetHashCode() for Foo.